# XSLT Clickable cells that travel trough worksheets

Tags: excel, xslt

and thanks in advance!

I already have a big XSLT file to parse my XML, and i was asked to create a kind of "Front Page" in my Excel file.

I need something like this in excel

- "1st Worksheet"
- "2nd-Worksheet"
- "3rd-Worksheet"

And when i click on these Links/Text/Cells (don't know how i should call it) im redirected to the corresponding Worksheet on my excel file.

The text that needs to appear in the cell is the same as the name of the worksheet so basically i need a cell that i can click that as the text "worksheet-1" inside it.

How could i include this feature in this piece of code?

```
<worksheet ss:Name="RELATÓRIO">
        <Table>
          <ss:Column ss:Width="150"/>
          <Row ss:Index="1">
            <Cell ss:Index="1">
               (code for Clickable cell goes here maybe?)
            </Cell>
          </Row>
        </Table>
      </worksheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a link the cell needs to look like this, I believe...

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="#Sheet1!A1">
  <Data ss:Type="String">1st Worksheet</Data>
</Cell>
```

Where "Sheet1" is whatever the name of the first worksheet is.

You would also need to include the relevant style under the `<styles>` tag in your document

```
<Style ss:ID="sLink" ss:Name="Hyperlink">
 <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#0563C1" ss:Underline="Single"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answear! 
I tried to use the code you gave me but it's giving me the object reference was not defined as an instance of an object error , I think it's probably due to the ss:HRef="#Sheet1!A1" perhaps? Can you explain how this part of the code works? If i have 2 worksheets named: "identificacao" and "instalacoes" what should go in there to access these ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to literally use the name of the sheet here, "Sheet1" was just an example. So, in your case it would be `ss:HRef="#identificacao!A1`

Comment: Ok i've changed and now its giving me a <h1>XLST Compilation Error <h1> 
And this piece of code x:Family="Swiss" is giving me  "namespace prefix 'x' is not defined. What should i do about this? Thanks in advance , you are literaly the only person answearing me XSLT questions, thank you very much man !

Comment: OK i've worked it out! Thank you very much your answear was very helpful! i just needed to change the x:Family="Swiss" to ss:Family="Swiss" :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the namespace declaration `xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"` to the XML

Comment: What's the difference between adding another namespace  and using only 1 ?
And 1 more thing! I got the first link working and it takes me to my first worksheet but i can't seem to make the second one work, i've tried :
'    



<Cell ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="#Instalacoes!A1">
<Cell ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="#Instalacoes!A2">
<Cell ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="#Instalacoes!B1">
<Cell ss:StyleID="sLink" ss:HRef="#Instalacoes">    

But nothing seems to work , thanks in advance!


'

Comment: Check your spelling, perhaps. I don't think it is case-sensitive, but maybe it needs a little `i` at the front, not a capital `I`.